# Read and write multiple line data file in C

Tags: c, file, binary, decimal

I'm having trouble reading and writing more than one line of data from a file.  The problem is to read multiple lines of binary from a file and convert it to decimal and write the multiple lines of decimal to a new file.  I had no problem getting the program to convert one line of binary to decimal the trouble comes when I have multiple lines.  Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NULL 0

int main() {
  FILE *ptdata, *ptresult;
  char bin[32];
  int i, r = 0, len;
  ptdata = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  ptresult = fopen("result.txt", "w");
  if (ptdata == NULL) printf("Error cannot open file");
  else {
    while (fgets(bin, 32, ptdata) != NULL);
    len = strlen(bin);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      r = r * 2 + (bin[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
    }
    printf("%d\n", r);
    fprintf(ptresult, "%d\n", r);
    fclose(ptdata);
    fclose(ptresult);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the error:

```
while(fgets(bin,32,ptdata)!=NULL); 
                               //^^^You have semicolon 
                              //here which ends the while loop
```

You should do the following:

```
 while(fgets(bin,32,ptdata)!=NULL){
    len = strlen(bin);
    r = 0 ;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
       r = r * 2 + (bin[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
    }

    printf("%d\n",r);
    fprintf(ptresult,"%d\n",r);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it now writes to multiple lines but for some reason it is not converting from binary to decimal right?

Comment: @TJM Your for loop seems converting binary to string, you may need to get some simple test cases to figure out where the errors are.

Comment: I have it partially fixed now, but it seems each line is adding onto the next so only the first line is correct.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to reset it at a '\n'

Comment: @TJM what is your input look like? how would you expect your output to be? You already have `\n` when you print, it should print newline.

Comment: my input file has "101011" on first line and "1011" on second line.  My output file reads "43" which is right and "349" on the second line which is wrong.

Comment: @TJM you have to reset r inside the while loop, that is, you have to process each line and store in r. see my updated post.

Comment: Thank you, it works better. On the for loop I had to change to len-1  On all sets of numbers and it works for all lines except the last one. For example going from 0000 to 1111 in binary will give an output of 1 to 14 then the last number will be 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop has been prematurely terminated

```
while(fgets(bin,32,ptdata)!=NULL);
                                ^^^
```